# A value of type "const char*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that would talk with someone but I have started learning C++ only 2 days ago so now I don't understand what to do to get rid of this error.
I want program to "cout" Hello if someone typed "Hello" but it doesn't work :(
It says:

> **A value of type "const char*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"**.

I tried to change "int" to *char, long long, unsigned char, unsigned long long, unsigned int* but it didn't work :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Answer;
        cout << "Hello! I'm a new born AI.";
        cin >> Answer;
        if (Answer = "Hello") //ERROR IS HERE {
            cout << "Hello" << endl;

        }

        }

        _getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Answer` is an `int` (it can only contain numbers) and you want to compare it to a string, what do you expect?

Comment: `Answer = "Hello"` makes no sense at all. Even if you were to do a comparison instead of an assignment

Comment: Probably: `int Answer;` -> `string Answer;` and `Answer = "Hello"` -> `Answer == "Hello"`

Comment: I would recommend you start with [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Trying to do these kind of programs after only two days learning C++ isn't a good idea. For example, you're using an assignment instead of a comparison. Also you can't compare a string with an integer in the way you did. And finally, isn't a good idea to use an ancient, non-standard library as `<conio.h>`. Better spend some time reading a good C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int Answer;
```

this states that `Answer` is a variable of type signed fixed bit count integer (typically 32 bits).

```
cin >> Answer;
```

this reads an integer from input and stores it in Answer.

`"Hello"` is a constant array of characters.

```
Answer = "Hello"
```

here `=` is assignment, not comparison.  `==` is comparison in C++.

Variables have types in C++.  You cannot store an array of characters in an `int`.  When that fails, it tries storing a pointer to the array of characters; that also fails.  It gives you an error.

Try making `Answer` a `std::string` instead of an `int`, and using `==` instead of `=` to compare it to `"Hello"`.

Your code will at least compile.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/7dEZhu).

Comment: Very "up-goer five" - I like!

Answer (score 0):

First, in c++ when you want to compare two objects/structs/literals, you use double equal `==`, not single equal `=`. Single equal is to assing a value, and unlike other programming languages where the meaning of `=` changes if you are in an "if" condition, in C++ you are assigning a value and returning that value to be evaluated by the condition.

Second, when you want to put text into a variable, you don't use and int variable like you are doing with "Answer", you use for example a std::string.